# Working around XamlRenderingBackgroundTask restrictions

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I'm still trying to wrap my head around the introduction of the XamlRenderingBackgroundTask for Universal apps. I'm currently planning my next app and I want it to have custom XAML bitmaps on tiles. Now I have a few questions on this:

All samples and references recommend to write the XamlRenderingBackgroundTask in C++. While I'm generally not opposed to that, I still have a few problems regarding to accessing the app's functionality while rendering the tile. E.g. I want to get the newest updates from a server and calculate locally on what I should show on the tile. The same functionality is used within the full app and is written in C#, and I think implementing the whole functionality in C++ would be a lot of work (server communication, SQLite and Linq usage). [This  sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Updating-a-tile-from-a-e0e492df) here shows one implementation of the XamlRenderingBackgroundTask but it is fairly limited in functionality because it only displays in time.

I have thought of a two possibilites to work around the XamlRenderingBackgroundTask restrictions and I wanted to get some opinions on what the best way would be:

1. Create two background tasks, one in C# and one in C++. The C# background task calculates the data that will be used and stores it locally for the C++ background task.
   The problem here is: Will the memory/CPU quotas hit the limit here? How can I guarantee the sequence (First C#, then C++)?
2. Store the C# logic in a WinRT component and reference it from the C++ background task. 
   I can't imagine this works, because the C# component will load the CLR runtime and I will hit the memory limit.

Also I have another question regarding background tasks:

Are the memory restrictions cummulative or is 16 MB on a 512 MB RAM phone device an upper limit that shall never be exceeded? E.g.:

I create an image and update the tile which takes 14 MB. If I flush the tile correclty etc. do I again have 16 MB to work with or only the remaining 2 MB?

The reason I ask is, because I wanted to allow the user to pin multiple (secondary) tiles to the start screen. If I only can create a tile once, it could never update (with XAML images) the other tiles.

I'd be thankful for any thoughts on this.